# VMware deploy OVF template causes vApps error

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter

I have a **VMware vSphere essentials** license, which includes one license for **vCenter Operations Manager Foundation**.  When I try to deploy the OVF template of  vCenter Operations Manager Foundation, I get the error:

> The OVF package requires support for vApps with multiple VMs."
>   "Details: Line 68: Unsupported element 'VirtualSystemCollection'

Here's a screenshot of this error:

[image]

The exact filename is `VMware-vcops-5.8.5.0-2532416-vapp.ova`.

I cannot create a new vApp in the *File > New* menu, most likely because my license does not support vApps.

How can I deploy this OVF template with my license?

**EDIT:** 
So I'm being told in the first comment I should not seek to install the *vCenter Operations Manager* and only install the *vCenter Server*.  Why did they specifically list the Operations Center under the Essentials Kit and link to it?

Screenshot from the website:

[image]

Comment: You don't want to the operations manager, you want the following.  https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=VCL-VSP510-VC-510B-EN&productId=284&rPId=3573

Comment: Ok, so ignore the *vCenter Operations Manager Foundation* link on the **vSphere Essentials Kit Details** page then?  I put a new screenshot in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just installing from the .iso file and abandoning the OVF package.  There are a few tutorials on how to do this.  Some are posted here:

https://www.virtuallyboring.com/vcenter-server-appliance-6-0-a-fresh-install/

http://www.virtxpert.com/installing-vmware-vcenter-server-appliance-6-0-vcsa/

http://www.vladan.fr/install-vmware-vcsa-6-0/